# how to trigger push notifications of firebase from an ios device using swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new iOS developer.

I am using firebase and I am trying to make a chat application in which I need to notify user when he/she receives any message.
For this purpose I tried firebase push notifications, but couldn't be able to trigger them when other user send the message.
The only way I found is using firebase console to send push notification, but it doesn't fulfill my requirements.
I've just configured local notifications.
Please guide me how can we trigger push notifications without using the firebase console.

Comment: You can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start. For example, if user A receive message, firebase automatically send event to deivce. In this case you can create your own notification.

Comment: @hmail Integration of Fire base Fallow  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start this and for code refer this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift

Comment: @DanielQ so you are suggesting me to use local notifications of ios which will be triggered automatically when observe method of firebase will work.?
i tried this but couldn't be able to make it work because i couldn't find a way to trigger local notifications on any event other then Calendar, Location and time.
please tell me how can i do it

Comment: Check this: https://makeapppie.com/2016/08/08/how-to-make-local-notifications-in-ios-10/

Comment: @DanialQ Sir, as i mentioned, i already implemented local notifications but coludn't be able to find a way to trigger them without timer, location or calendar trigger.
in the proposed tutorial time trigger is being used. but i want to trigger my notifications on data change ( in the observe method of firebase).

Comment: @DanielQ Sir,
var trig = UNNotificationTrigger(coder: NSCoder)
this might be the trigger i am looking for but couldn't be able to find that how can i use it.
i googled it a lot but not a single tutorial on it :(

Comment: you should try OneSignal which is free and very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution after struggling for almost 1 month.

These are the basic steps

1. Firs off all you need to make sure that you have an active apple developers account
2. just enable firebase push notifications
   [here ie the link of youtube video for this step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBw5tuTvKd4)
3. Now your app is set up for firebase remote notifications but we can only trigger them from the firebase console so here is the tricky part. [here is the link of video to enable firebase console on your mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ&t=326s)
4. for the first time it will be good to see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0&t=366s) too because in this video they'll learn to write code in node.js and deploy it to the firebase.
5. Now if anyone wants to make an API instead of making a trigger then here is a code of API which sends the notification to other user by getting his FCM token from the firebase...
   You can modify it according to your need

i am finding it difficult to post code in its exact form but the code **starts from here**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin =require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref=admin.database().ref();
exports.sendNotification=functions.https.onRequest((req,res) =>{

    const id = req.query.id
    const title = req.query.title
    const message = req.query.message
    const key = req.query.key
    // admin.database.ref()

    const payload ={

        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: message,
            //badge: '1',
            sound: 'default',
        }
    };

    console.log('Param [key] is '+key);

    const keys = [] ;

    ref.child('keys').once('value')
    .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {

            const loopKey=childSnap.val().key;
            keys.push(loopKey);

        })

        return keys;
    })
    .then(keys=>{

        //console.log('Keys in database : '+keys.join());

        if(keys.indexOf(key)>-1)
        {
            if(!key || !id || !message)
            {
                res.status(400).send('Bad request');
            }
            else{
                ref.child('users').child(id).child('fcmToken').once('value')
                .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.val()){
                        const token = snapshot.val()
                        console.log(token);
                        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload).then(response =>{
                            res.status(200).send('Notification sent')
                        });
                    }   
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("In-valid key : "+key);

            res.status(400).send('Bad request');
        }   
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    });

});
```

**ends at this point**

this is the function to store your fcm to database

```
func postToken(token: String, id: String){
    print("FCM Token \(token)")
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id)
    ref.child("fcmToken").setValue(token)
}
```

here is the function which i used to trigger this API

```
func sendNotification(id: String, title: String, message: String){
    var url = "your URL"
    var urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: url)
    urlComponents?.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: self.apiKey),
        URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: id),
        URLQueryItem(name: "title", value: title),
        URLQueryItem(name: "message", value: message)
    ]

    Alamofire.request((urlComponents?.url)!).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response.response)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.result)
    }

}
```

the above API was written according to my database structure. you can change it easily for your own structure.

after doing this all you'll be able to send your notifications after hitting the URL

Hope it will give a nice idea to you people to work with your own notifications according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send Push Notifications from my code using `PushNotificationSender` class from this article - 
https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/push-notifications-firebase-swift-5